# Azure Logic App trigger a REST Api in Azure Api manegment

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-api-management

I have an azure Logic app and azure API Management(APIM). and I would like to call the APIs in the Azure APIM from Logic app at different intervals.
I can find the Azure API management in the list of steps in the Azure Logic App but after adding there is nothing there.
I wonder how can I connect my Azure APIM resource to this?
[image]

Comment: If you select "Choose an Azure Management API action", does it not show a list of actions?

Comment: Hi, may I know if the solution provided below helps your problem ?

Comment: @HuryShen changing this is a big change for our organization because the other team is responsible for this. but it was a great clue to search more about it

Answer (score 0):

According to some test, if we choose "**Consumption**" as pricing tier when we create the APIM, we can't see it in logic app "**Azure API Management**" connector. So please choose other pricing tier(such as "**Developer**") for your APIM.

Comment: good to know, thanks! I did not know about this. In general, do we need any connector for APIM?

Comment: @ShrnPrmshr If you can't change the pricing tier of the APIM and you still want to call the api. Why not use "[HTTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http#add-an-http-action)" action to request the url of api in APIM directly ?

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. I do not know maybe I just try to do something different to learn. I read the doc about the connector and because I am a bit new to logic app so I confused by my thoughts