# Azure APIM API is not visible in Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-api-management

I created a consumption-based Logic App and are trying to call an API from API Management Service (Consumption Tier).
However, the OpenAPI I imported from a swagger file in APIM doesn't show up in Logic Apps.

I don't understand what I missed here.

APIM

[image]

Logic Apps Issue

[image]

I followed the same steps from this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FsF9m4-sYwg&t=2109s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I created a consumption-based Logic App and are trying to call an API from API Management Service (Consumption Tier). However, the OpenAPI I imported from a swagger file in APIM doesn't show up in Logic Apps.

In order to use the APIs from Azure API Management services in logic app, you need to create APIM instance with pricing tier (**Developer**) other than **Consumption Pricing Tier**.

I have an APIM Instance with Developer pricing tier and a consumption logic app. I am able to see the APIs which are there in APIM when I select the APIM connector in logic app as shown below.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

In this way you can use the APIM connector in logic app.

**References**-

[Azure Logic App trigger a REST Api in Azure Api manegment - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63687565/azure-logic-app-trigger-a-rest-api-in-azure-api-manegment).